# Surface Isotropic and Shear Stress

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, fluid-dynamics, stress-strain, biophysics

I am going over a 1987 biomechanics paper looking at surface shear stress in a biological membrane, which behaves analogous to a liquid in the plane of the membrane (see image/sketch below).
[image: Thick Anisotropic Liquid Shell]
[image]
The principal planes here are oriented along
$${ z,\phi,r}$$ i.e. the axial, circumferential and radial directions
respectively.

The paper develops an analysis for tethers (hollow membrane cylinders pulled from biological membranes as a response to forces applied to the membrane) as thick liquid shells where the membrane stresses are isotropic in the plane of the membrane, aka the same in magnitude along the axial and circumferential directions, and anisotropic in the radial direction.

The membrane is modeled as having zero shear rigidity along the surface due to its liquid-analogous characteristics (see excerpt below):
[image: Equations]

I find this confusing because I think of shear stress as any stress that is parallel to the plane of the surface as opposed to normal stresses which are perpendicular to the surface plane.

Then should a zero surface shear stress require that?

$$\bar \sigma = 0.5(\sigma_z +\sigma_\phi)=0 $$

$$ \sigma_s = 0.5(\sigma_z -\sigma_\phi)=0 $$

which should imply that
$$|\sigma_z|=|\sigma_\phi|$$

Possibly,my confusion is resulting from it not being very clear if these stresses are vectors or scalars.
It seems obvious that the vectors
$$\sigma_z,\sigma_\phi$$ are not the same. So they must mean that the magnitudes alone are the same.

I drew rough sketches (see below) of that versus a separate scenario; the isotropic/shear stresses and am now confused. I changed the phrasing a bit from the original one and
introduced a pulling stress and termed the other components the stress response in the membrane and looked at a point P on the surface and the stresses on it:
[image: stresses]
The circumferential stress here both pulls away from and pushes inward towards the point. While the pulling stress pulls away from the point upwards and towards it from downwards. Otoh the reactive stress in the membrane is directed towards it from the top and away from it downwards.

And so effectively all the sums cancel out. Does that make sense?
Intuitively possibly I get why the surface isotropic stress has the same magnitude in all directions.

Maybe someone can explain it more elegantly?

**I don't have a specific question so much as a more elegant and completely accurate way to think about this.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks chemomechanics..I will read that thread and see. Appreciate it. It definitely looks helpful.

Comment: You issue is that stress is a 2nd order tensor, not a vector (1st order tensor).  As such, for planes oriented perpendicular to directions other than the principal directions. there are shear tractions.  In this case, what they are trying to show is that the in-plane components of the stress tensor are isotropic, which results on zero shear tractions on all planes.  Get yourself a book on "sstrength of materials," and read about stresses and strains.  In your situation also, the stretches in the axial and circumferential directions must also be equal.

Comment: Okay thanks Chet - that was exactly what I needed. I do have a handout on tensors. A bit uphill but I will review that.

Comment: You need to really consult analysis specifically aimed at the stress tensor, and how to use the so-caled Caushy stress relationship to determine the traction on a plane of arbitrary orientation..

Comment: Thank you Chet. I checked my main textbook for this "Mechanics and Thermodynamics of Biomembranes" by Evans and Skalak. On pages 10, 82-84 and 134 it references tensors (which are also referred to as the force resultant matrix; they mention a Finger's strain tensor which is a  deformation matrix; the Alamansi/spatial strain tensor and the Green's/material strain tensor). However, tensors are not really formally defined. I have a pdf called "A Gentle Introduction to Tensors" by Porat which I must wade into-oh well ;-/. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: See Appendix A or B of Transport Phenomena by Bird, Stewart, and Lightfoot..

Comment: Okay thanks. Apparently archive.org has it. https://archive.org/details/transportphenome00rbyr

Comment: A follow up comment-this post was the result of my finding a 1987 paper by Waugh and Hochmuth "Mechanical Equilibrium of Thick, Hollow, Liquid Membrane Cylinders" confusingly worded and scrambling my understanding of the basic ME. Which is clearer in this paper: "Bending Resistance and Chemically Induced Moments in Membrane Bilayers". Evans. 1974. The most basic concepts are explained in this page on pure bending: http://emweb.unl.edu/NEGAHBAN/Em325/11-Bending/Bending.htm

Comment: The surface isotropic stress is the result of areal strains due to the resistance of the surface to expansion or compression. But the way they conceptually tied that to zero shear rigidity confused me.

Comment: I wanted to thank Chet Miller for the suggestion re: Tensors. It is really making it easy for me to grasp all these concepts. Somehow I made it through engineering school snd grad school without a primer in tensors (the sole course in linear algebra I took did not cover them) so I am finding this a very useful exercise. Evans and Skalak does not explicitly refer to them as tensors, but it makes it much easier to grasp with that context. Thanks Chet!